# Does the ND (NoDerivatives) clause forbid the distribution of any form of text or data mining based on papers with such a license?

Tags: publications, legal-issues, license, creative-commons

I was reading "Your Guide to Publishing Open Access with Elsevier" 
(URL: https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/pdf_file/0020/181433/openaccessbooklet_May.pdf  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170418030710/https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/pdf_file/0020/181433/openaccessbooklet_May.pdf))) and saw this table on page 6:

[image: Table describing permissions granted by various licences]

Why does the [CC-BY-NC-ND 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/) in this Elsevier only allow "Text & data
min[ing]" for private use only and not for distribution? I understand one cannot make commercial use of it but does the ND (NoDerivatives) clause forbid the distribution of any form of text or data mining based on papers with such a license?

ND (NoDerivatives) is described by creativecommons.org [as follows](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/):

> If you remix, transform, or build upon the material, you may not distribute the modified material.

It's not obvious to me that the output of a text mining or data mining program necessarily qualifies as a derivative.

Comment: Either way, that's a misrepresentation of the license. "Non-commercial" means CC BY-NC, not NC-ND. Not that you'd expect them to get it right, though.

Comment: @E.P. yes I hope the authors don't get misled by this when submitting to some Elsevier journals. ND has nothing to do with NC.

Comment: Other problems with this table: translations are not allowed with "ND" (as mentioned by Anonymous Mathematician), and I think "Reuse portions […] in other works" is also not allowed with "ND" (except, of course, to the extent that is allowed by law). Question on Open Source SE: [Can I leave out parts of a CC BY-ND licensed work when distributing it?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/965/138)

Comment: @unor: The [4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/legalcode) used here allows one to "reproduce and Share the Licensed Material, in whole or in part", which seems to allow quoting just a portion (but not of course reusing it in any way that would require modifications).  By contrast, the [3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0/legalcode) from the Open Source SE question does not seem to allow this.

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician: Wow, didn’t know that they changed this for 4.0 -- thanks for the notice!

Comment: @unor: Yeah, I thought this was a mistake in the Elsevier table too, until I checked the 4.0 license to try to confirm that it was definitely wrong.

Answer (score 17):

According to the [Guide to Mining CC-Licensed Material](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Content_mining)  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170420142221/https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Content_mining)), the answer may depend on what you produce with the text/data mining.  If you run some calculations and then write a paper describing what you learned, then that paper would not be a derivative work.  If you produce a data set based on the mining, then that data set might be considered an adaptation of the original work.  The guide does not propose a test for distinguishing between these possibilities.  If it matters to you, I expect you would need to consult a lawyer.

Incidentally, I wouldn't take Elsevier's table too seriously.  For example, it suggests that the CC BY-NC-ND license allows distributing a translation (since it doesn't have a "not for distribution" note there).  However, that just isn't true: the [license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/legalcode) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170420142313/https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/legalcode))  explicitly lists translations as being adapted material that cannot be shared.